# how to change the default http method in wcf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Do i have to write the attribute `[WebGet]` above every operation to get access via "GET"?
I want that my default ACCESS METHOD will be "GET" not "POST". Is there a way to do it on web.config/app.config?

Comment: I guess you need to specify what kind of operation your method serves whether it is a GET or POST operation. I dont think you cannot get around without specifying an attribute. The default for WebInvoke is POST but for GET you would need to use WebGet attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do it only in the configuration. You'll need to create a new behavior, derived from `WebHttpBehavior`, and change the default (add a [WebGet] if nothing is there) - see code below. Then, if you want, you can define a behavior configuration extension to use that behavior via config.

```
public class StackOverflow_10970052
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public class Service
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
        [OperationContract]
        public int Subtract(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
        [OperationContract, WebInvoke]
        public string Echo(string input)
        {
            return input;
        }
    }
    public class MyGetDefaultWebHttpBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
    {
        public override void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            foreach (var operation in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
            {
                if (operation.Behaviors.Find<WebGetAttribute>() == null && operation.Behaviors.Find<WebInvokeAttribute>() == null)
                {
                    operation.Behaviors.Add(new WebGetAttribute());
                }
            }

            base.ApplyDispatchBehavior(endpoint, endpointDispatcher);
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Service), new WebHttpBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new MyGetDefaultWebHttpBehavior());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/Add?x=6&y=8"));

        c = new WebClient();
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/Subtract?x=6&y=8"));

        c = new WebClient();
        c.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        Console.WriteLine(c.UploadString(baseAddress + "/Echo", "\"hello world\""));

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```